# Decode base64 JSON file - in ajax method

Tags: jquery, ajax, base64

I have a JSON file board.json that I read with ajax method below using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
$.ajax({//ajax method to load the board.json and call the loadBoard() function on success
    'async': false,
    'global': false,
    type:'GET',
    dataType:'json',
    url:'board.json',
    success:function(data){
        map = data;
        loadBoard();
    }
});
```

board.json is encoded with base64. But decoded it should look like this:

```
[
{
    "name":"Category1",
    "questions":[
        {
            "value":100,
           "question":"",
            "answers":[
                {
                    "text":"",
                    "correct":true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "value":200,
           "question":"",
            "answers":[
                {
                    "text":"",
                    "correct":true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "value":300,
           "question":"",
            "answers":[
                {
                    "text":"",
                    "correct":true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "value":400,
           "question":"",
            "answers":[
                {
                    "text":"",
                    "correct":true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name":"Category2",
    "questions":[
        {
            "value":100,
           "question":"",
            "answers":[
                {
                    "text":"",
                    "correct":true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "value":200,
           "question":"",
            "answers":[
                {
                    "text":"",
                    "correct":true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "value":300,
           "question":"",
            "answers":[
                {
                    "text":"",
                    "correct":true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "value":400,
           "question":"",
            "answers":[
                {
                    "text":"",
                    "correct":true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name":"Category4",
    "questions":[
        {
            "value":100,
           "question":"",
            "answers":[
                {
                    "text":"",
                    "correct":true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "value":200,
           "question":"",
            "answers":[
                {
                    "text":"",
                    "correct":true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "value":300,
           "question":"",
            "answers":[
                {
                    "text":"",
                    "correct":true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "value":400,
           "question":"",
            "answers":[
                {
                    "text":"",
                    "correct":true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name":"Category5",
    "questions":[
        {
            "value":100,
           "question":"",
            "answers":[
                {
                    "text":"",
                    "correct":true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "value":200,
           "question":"",
            "answers":[
                {
                    "text":"",
                    "correct":true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "value":300,
           "question":"",
            "answers":[
                {
                    "text":"",
                    "correct":true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "value":400,
           "question":"",
            "answers":[
                {
                    "text":"",
                    "correct":true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name":"Category6",
    "questions":[
        {
            "value":100,
           "question":"",
            "answers":[
                {
                    "text":"",
                    "correct":true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "value":200,
           "question":"",
            "answers":[
                {
                    "text":"",
                    "correct":true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "value":300,
           "question":"",
            "answers":[
                {
                    "text":"",
                    "correct":true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "value":400,
           "question":"",
            "answers":[
                {
                    "text":"",
                    "correct":true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I have tried to use `atob()` and also the following decode function:

```
function b64DecodeUnicode(str) {
// Going backwards: from bytestream, to percent-encoding, to original string.
return decodeURIComponent(atob(str).split('').map(function(c) {
    return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  }).join(''));
}
```

But both gives me a string. How can I convert the string into a multidimensional array of objects as in the decoded JSON file above?

EDIT: Here is loadBoard() function below:

```
function loadBoard(){//function that turns the board.json (loaded in the the map variable) into a jeopardy board
var board = $('#main-board');
var columns = map.length;
var column_width = parseInt(12/columns); //get the width/12 rounded down, to use the bootstrap column width appropriate for the number of categories
var tile_count = 0;
console.log(columns);
$.each(map, function(i,category){
    //load category name
    var header_class = 'text-center col-md-' + column_width;
    if (i === 0 && columns % 2 != 0){ //if the number of columns is odd, offset the first one by one to center them
        header_class += ' col-md-offset-1';
    }
    $('.panel-heading').append(
        '<div class="'+header_class+'"><h4>'+category.name+'</h4></div>'
    );
    //add column
    var div_class = 'category col-md-' + column_width;
    if (i === 0 && columns % 2 != 0){
        div_class += ' col-md-offset-1';
    }
    board.append('<div class="'+div_class+'" id="cat-'+i+'" data-category="'+i+'"></div>');
    var column = $('#cat-'+i);
    $.each(category.questions, function(n,question){
        //add questions
        tile_count ++;
        double = 0;
        if (question.double) { double = 1; }
         
        column.append('<div class="well question unanswered" id="tile' + tile_count + '" data-question="'+n+'" data-double="' + double + '">'+question.value+'</div>')
             
    });
});
$('.panel-heading').append('<div class="clearfix"></div>')
```

}

The encoded JSON file is shown below:

```
"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"
```

Comment: You need to review what "JSON" is.  Hint: it *is* a string and *only* a string.   Try `var obj = JSON.parse(decoded_string)` - in your case:  `map = JSON.parse(b64DecodeUnicode(data))`

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes I tried that. But loadBoard() doesn't show me the categories. Nothing is outputted on the webpage. I have added the loadBoard() function in the question.

Comment: Doesn't mean much without the encoded string

Comment: @freedomn-m I added it to the question

Comment: Looks like your source file is not valid JSON - try it in https://www.base64decode.org/ (or other online decoder) or look at the output of `console.log(b64DecodeUnicode(data))` then put that in https://jsonformatter.org/json-parser (or other online parser) to see errors.

Comment: You should also have seen errors on `JSON.parse` line before your "loadBoard" would even be called

Comment: Was your original *object* base64 encoded?  And not stringified?  That's not how JSON works.  Back to my first comment.  JSON is a *string representation of an object* - it is not an *object*.

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned. It seems to be some kind of problem in the JSON formatting. I get this error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Also I should mention that I encode the data using PHP and base64_encode((serialize($data)) function and then passing it on with json_encode(). I have to look further into it to see where the problem is.

Comment: Problem solved! The problem was that i serialized the information in PHP. So I had to unserialize it in Javascript using the equivalent function for unserializing in Javascript.